# Bookmarklet to open new tab with Xpath from current page as URL arguments

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url, xpath, bookmarklet

I would like to create a bookmarklet that can use 3 Xpath from the current page to build a Url with the xpath as the arguments.

I have tried to find an existing bookmarklet that was similar that I would be able to modify. I am not a programmer, just someone trying to improve the efficiency of a process they have to do frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple example to read the value using the xpath and then open new tab with the xpath output.

Save the below javascript as a bookmarklet and click when you are on any post to see the origninal post user profile.

```
javascript:{
    var xResults = document.evaluate("(//div[@class='post-signature owner grid--cell']//a)[2]", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
    var url = xResults.snapshotItem(0).href;
    window.open(url);
}
```

Comment: This should give you an idea how to develop the bookmarklet, please update the script as per your need. Note: This is a generic solution, took SO as sample app as OP did not provided the url and xpath.